# How to link a specific header function

Tags: c

Hey so I am trying to create a CTF challenge which uses a specific version of dlmalloc. I have the source code for the specific version of dlmalloc saved as malloc-2.6.1.c. Could someone tell me how I will be able to statically link that source code into the binary.
Here's the source code of the CTF challenge if it helps.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void winner()
{
  printf("that wasn't too bad now, was it? @ %d\n", time(NULL));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *a, *b, *c;

  a = malloc(32);
  b = malloc(32);
  c = malloc(32);

  strcpy(a, argv[1]);
  strcpy(b, argv[2]);
  strcpy(c, argv[3]);

  free(c);
  free(b);
  free(a);

  printf("dynamite failed?\n");
}
```

Comment: Just link it: `gcc whatever.o malloc-2.6.1.o`

Comment: I would declare it as an .h and include it with the correct path.

Comment: I do have a header file of that specific malloc too, but could you explain how I will be able to do that. If I use gcc whatever.c /usr/include/malloc.h, malloc is still dynamically linked

Comment: May be you need to wrap your malloc function of `dlmalloc ` and then use `--wrap=` option of gcc to override `glibc` provided malloc function.

Comment: *Note. you don't link a header file, you include a header file into your source file. You link with libraries and/or object files.* Having said this, go with @Barmar's advice and compile and link the module. The standard function in the standard library will only be linked if references are *not resolved* earlier in the linking process.

Comment: You don't need a header file for it, since the declaration of `malloc()` should be the same as in the standard header.